# Running Powershell Script in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, azure-active-directory

So I'm trying to create a workbook that will pull down all info from AzureAD using powershell.(C:\Script\VBA Testing\ExportOffice365UsersAndGroups.ps1)

and then send commands to powershell and run them.

I've thought of different ways such as creating a ps1 file:

```
strpath = "C:\Script\VBA Testing\"
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strpath & "Testing.ps1")
oFile.WRiteline "Connect-AzureAD"
oFile.Close
```

then just running it to creating a batch file that will run the script after creating it as running powershell scripts seem to be hard.

I am able to start powershell and run the command but the issue is that for some reason its not noticing the modules i have run.

```
"Powershell -noexit -File ""C:\Script\VBA Testing\Testing.ps1"""
```

just returns that the module AzureAD does not exist but if i just start powershell and try it, it works fine.

Same if i set it to run from C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Anyone have any bright ideas that might help me?

Pretty much I just need it to do Connect-AzureAD then run a few lines.. What im thinking is that every change i do will update the ps1 file and in the end i press a button and that will run the entire script.

A lot of users are running 32bit excel so need something that will check if its running 32bit and if so, run powershell 64bit instead of 32bit.

Comment: Are you just trying to load data from Azure AD into Excel? What else are you trying to do? What you propose (writing to a batch file then running it) is quite convoluted and unreliable. Just solve the immediate errors, i.e. the " module AzureAD does not exist"

Comment: I want to first extract all the data then make changes to them and have those changes sent back into Azure AD.. My goal is to just run the powershell script i have to get all the user info.. then for every change i make a new line will be created in my script(this i can do) then when pressing a submitting this script will be run... so one script needs to be ran in the beginning then one in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test it works in the **64 bit Excel** VBA project.

So please have a try to use the 64 bit Excel to test.

If I run the command in the 32 bit excel VBA I also can reproduce the issue that you mentioned.

We could know that Connect-AzureAD  in the powershell `AzureAD` or `AzureAD preview` module. I also found that I can't `Import-Module AzureAD` in the 32 bit VBA project.

In the AzureADPreview/AzureAD.psd1 file, I found that

```
ProcessorArchitecture = 'Amd64'
```

And I also try to update the `ProcessorArchitecture = "None"` or `ProcessorArchitecture = "X86"`, but both of don't work.

**powershell script:**

```
Import-Module AzureAD -Force  //force to load the AzureAD module 
Connect-AzureAD
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. Was on vacation.
Issue is that we have some people with 32bit and others with 64bit excel.. is there a way to add a if 32bit do this and if 64bit do this? so it can run 64bit powershell from 32bit? 90% of our members have 32bit so need to find a solution so it can run from 32bit.